# Are three levels of select a performance issue?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I'm fairly new to Postgres, and I'm trying to implements some complex functionality.

The following query works:

```
select (
    select ts as start
    from (
        select *
        from events
        where (reason = 'START' or reason = 'STOP')
        and ts < ?
        and user = ?
        order by ts desc
        limit 1
    ) as subquery_start
    where reason = 'START'
    ),(
    select ts as stop
    from (
        select *
        from events
        where (reason = 'START' or reason = 'STOP')
        and ts > ?
        and user = ?
        order by ts
        limit 1
    ) as subquery_stop
    where reason = 'STOP'
);
```

It finds whether the user, at a time, is between START and STOP events, returning:

```
           start           |           stop            
---------------------------+---------------------------
 2018-06-01 10:44:55.52+01 | 2018-06-01 10:45:07.52+01
(1 row)
```

whether they are not:

```
 start | stop 
-------+------
       | 
(1 row)
```

or whether they're just after a START and a later STOP is not yet present:

```
           start           | stop           
---------------------------+------
 2018-06-01 10:44:55.52+01 | 
(1 row)
```

Is it possible to simplify such a query, given that I want one row returned, as in the examples above?

Will three levels of nested selects cause performance issues?

Comment: Note both subqueries could return more than one row. This final result will be the carthesian product of the two subqueries. You *think* you solve this with the LIMIT, but the *matched* rows could actually be unrelated. The correct solution will probably involve a window function.

Comment: This actually looks like a fairly good query.  The two innermost queries will only return at most one row each.  Each of the encapsulating queries only need deal with 1 row apiece, so I would expect your performance to be about as good as it can get.  The only optimization I can think of would be to only return TS and Reason from the two innermost queries.

Comment: Why does your inner query use `where (reason = 'START' or reason = 'STOP')` then the outer query applies `where reason = 'START'`? What point is there to doing this? Why not have no outer query and use `where reason = 'START'` on the table? BTW `reason in ('START', 'STOP')` performs better than an `or`.

Comment: @Bohemian that's what makes the whole thing work. consider the case when the target time is after a 'STOP' and before a 'START'

Comment: @joop, I sreiously doubt that multiple rows thing. of course the rows will be unrelated, there's no formal relation, but what they will be is the nearest neighbours.

Comment: what do you expect to return if the very last row is the only start reason or the very first row is the only stop reason?

Answer (score 1):

It looks pretty good to me. the inner selects being limit 1 will use any index you have on the 'user,ts' column-pair,

The best index for this query would be on
 `events(user,ts) where (reason = 'START' or reason = 'STOP')`
but on `events(user,ts)` should be almost as good.

possibly a clearer way to get a similar result would be

```
WITH subquery_before AS (
        select ts,reason
        from events
        where (reason = 'START' or reason = 'STOP')
        and ts < ?
        and user = ?
        order by ts desc
        limit 1
    ),
subquery_after AS (
        select ts,reason
        from events
        where (reason = 'START' or reason = 'STOP')
        and ts > ?
        and user = ?
        order by ts
        limit 1
    ) 
SELECT
  subquery_before.ts AS start,
  subquery_after.ts AS stop
WHERE  subquery_before.reason = 'START'
  AND  subquery_after.reason = 'STOP'
```

Answer (score 0):

use window functions to avoid nesting altogether

```
SELECT 

    CASE WHEN FIRST_VALUE(reason) OVER w1 = 'START'
      THEN FIRST_VALUE(ts) OVER w1 
      ELSE NULL 
    END start, 
    CASE WHEN LAST_VALUE(reason) OVER w2 = 'STOP'
      THEN LAST_VALUE(ts) OVER w2 
      ELSE NULL 
    END stop
FROM events
WHERE (reason = 'START' or reason = 'STOP')  
  AND ts > ? AND ts < ?
  AND user = ?
WINDOW w1 AS (ORDER BY reason != 'START', ts)
       w2 AS (ORDER BY reason = 'STOP', ts)
LIMIT 1
```

This works because Boolean values are sorted `False`, `True`.

So, `w1` puts all the rows where `reason = 'START'` at the top, and within that group sorts by ts. We pick out the `ts` in the first row with `FIRST_VALUE`. Similarly, we get the last `ts` where `reason = 'STOP'`

This detects the following cases:

1. No `START` or `STOP` reasons were found for user in the time range (no rows returned)
2. Either `START` or `STOP` (but not both) reasons were found for user in the time range (row is returned with 1 null)
3. The first `START` `ts` is after the last `STOP` `ts` (e.g. if the very last row ordered by ts is a only one where `reason = 'START'` (comparison of the returned row's `start` & `stop` values
4. The `START` `ts` < `STOP` `ts` as expected. (row is returned with both columns properly populated)